# Write to file text from terminal using fgets()

Tags: c, linux, terminal

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <cstdio>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char buff[512];
    int desc;
    int lb;
    desc = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY);
    if(desc == -1) {
        perror("error");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(lb=fgets(buff,512,stdin) > 0) {
        write(desc,buff,lb);

    }
    
}
```

In C on linux I have to write to a file passed as an argv text from terminal written by user, using fgets().The program is supposed to work in a loop and  if user writes "end" the program stops.
I guess now the program is going to write to the file text from the stdin, not really sure how to end the program while the "end" condition.

Comment: Welcome to SO. you might want to take a look at `strcmp()` and `write()`

Comment: Maybe [`fopen`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) (see the example) is better suited for writing text files than `open`.

Comment: Not really sure how to get text from terminal into the buffer

Comment: The "terminal" is `stdin`. You can read it however you prefer, like `fgets()` as used here.

Comment: Note: `open()` is a really low-level call that should not be used unless you have a very specific requirement for unbuffered IO. Use `fopen()` instead and `FILE*`.

Comment: **WARNING**: Unless you're absolutely certain that `n < argc` is true, **do not** reference `argv[n]`. You will exercise an invalid pointer.

Comment: I have requirement to use open() instead of fopen()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Not really sure how to get text from terminal into the buffer "*

`fopen()` is a better option (per comments on `open()`). The following assumes a text file, and that a valid [filespec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filespec) is on the command line.  It will read until it sees 'end', then capture that as the last line...

( Will also exit on the following: for UNIX systems  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, or Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. )

```
#define INSTRUCTIONS "Entered text will be written to file %s.\n\
When finished with desired input press '<enter>end'.\n\
This will close and save the file, and exit the program.\n\
Begin Here:\n"
 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[80] = {0};
    if(argv < 1) 
    {
        printf("missing filespec in command line\nHit any key to exit.");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    printf(INSTRUCTIONS, argv[1]);
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");
    if(fp)
    {
        while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))//reads until EOF
        {
            fputs(buffer, fp);
            buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;//clear newline
            //looks for a new line containing only end\n
            if(strcmp(buffer, "end") == 0)
            {
                fclose(fp);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is this any different than the example?

Comment: @tadman - was still editing, should not have posted so early.

Comment: Fair enough, but the question seems to be dealing with the `"end"` matching part.